# Is there any matlab build-in function for solving 1-d wave equation numerically?

Tags: matlab, pde

I searched the documentation of matlab and found it can solve 2d and 3d wave equations numerically by functions like "hyperbolic" and "parabolic".

Strangely I could not find build-in functions to solve 1d wave equation? Anyone knows the name of the function to solve 1d wave equation? Thank you!

Comment: Quite a few of them on Google.

Comment: Crossposted on Math.se http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1426276/131807

Comment: @Lorehead Yes but I think it is very odd if matlab does not have a build-in function to do this. So I am asking if there is any build-in function to do this.

Comment: Actually, I am not surprised, because without good knowledge of underlying maths is this job really tricky. Of course, you can write a function "parabolic" but what about boundary conditions, stability, convergence etc. All of this should be adjusted to a particular problem and trying to produce something too general can do more harm than good. My huble opinion.